# iOS Swift - How to add a uneditable suffix to a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, formatter

How do I programmatically add a suffix ("kr") to an UITextView?

**Thanks!**

Comment: when you want to add "kr" in the textview?

Comment: Do you mean add it to each word in the text view?

Comment: use this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8288305/6846532

Comment: I meant to add after the text in the textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is when the user is typing to indicate a currency value.

In viewDidLoad assign your textview delegate (or wherever you wish to assign the delegate):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextView.delegate = self
}
```

And then to add the suffix to the textview when user is typing

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    if string.characters.count > 0 {
        amountTypedString += string
        let newString = amountTypedString + "kr"
        myTextView.text = newString
    } else {
        amountTypedString = String(amountTypedString.characters.dropLast())
        if amountTypedString.characters.count > 0 {
            let newString = amountTypedString + "kr"
            myTextView.text = newString
        } else {
            myTextView.text = "0kr"
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: `if string.characters.count > 0 {` should be written `if !string.isEmpty {` the same applies to `if !amountTypedString.isEmpty {`

Comment: This answer has far too many issues. It only works if there's no text selection and the cursor is always at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Also another solution that may help someone is to extend UITextField and add a phantom label centered in the view, this phantom label should be updated with the same text value from the UITextField and have the same font size. After that place the suffix constrained to the trailing constraint of the phantom label.

```
class TextWithSuffix: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {


private lazy var textPhantom = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
    label.textColor = .clear
    return label
}()

private lazy var suffix = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "kr"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label.textColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self
    textAlignment = .center
    font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 26)
    textColor = .white

    addConstrainedSubviews(textPhantom, suffix)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        textPhantom.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        textPhantom.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),

        suffix.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textPhantom.trailingAnchor, constant: 2),
        suffix.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textPhantom.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func textField(
    _ textField: UITextField,
    shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
    replacementString string: String
) -> Bool {
    let currentString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)[enter image description here][1]
    textPhantom.text = newString
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: But this prevents anything else from being the text field's delegate. That's a big issue in many cases. You should also avoid hardcoding the font sizes. Consider using `UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)`. And what is `addConstrainedSubviews`?

Comment: The addConstrainedSubviews is just a extension to reduce verbosity of
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and addSubView(view).
And the fonts were just to differentiate the text suffix style in the example, but thanks for the tip.